# Surface mesh from labeled 3D points

Tags: algorithms, computational-geometry, mesh-generation

I'm trying to figure out how to create a surface mesh from a set of labeled 3D points. The 3D object could be something like part of a cave system or asteroid where there would be parts of the surface not visible from looking on the outside. Each point has a radius and not all points are on the surface. The output should be a Nx3 matrix (coordinate matrix) and another matrix to represent the triangles of the mesh (as in the Libigl tutorial https://libigl.github.io/tutorial/). What algorithms are there to find the points on the surface and what algorithms can create meshes from 3D points with complicated pockets? A example 2D slice is below.

[image]

Comment: Is it both the outer surface of a body and also surfaces of internal cavities in it?

Comment: I've updated the question to show a 2D slice example. It's just the outer surface with no internal cavities.

Comment: I would look into Delaunay triangulation for this, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delaunay_triangulation

Comment: I am copying these from wikipedia article "Surface Triangulation", so I am not going to put it as an answer. It looks like marching method is a good simple option and "E. Hartmann: Geometry and Algorithms for COMPUTER AIDED DESIGN, p. 81", "E. Hartmann: A marching method for the triangulation of surfaces, The Visual Computer (1998), 14, pp. 95–108", "S. Akkouche & E Galin: Adaptive Implicit Surface Polygonization Using Marching Triangles, COMPUTER GRAPHICS forum (2001), Vol. 20, pp. 67–80" are some papers describe the method.

Comment: Also I found the following research report: https://www.cs.jhu.edu/~misha/Fall13b/Papers/Cazals06.pdf "Delaunay Triangulation Based Surface Reconstruction: Ideas and Algorithms" by Frederic Cazals and Joachim Giesen

Comment: Your surface suppose to be a close manifold right? If yes, look at here: https://lorensen.github.io/VTKExamples/site/Cxx/Points/PoissonExtractSurface/

Comment: Yep, closed manifold. I'll check that out. So far, I have looked at Delaunay triangulation. I've seen two methods that might work. I've found the Marching Cubes algorithm http://www.cs.carleton.edu/cs_comps/0405/shape/marching_cubes.html . I've also found Alpha Shapes https://graphics.stanford.edu/courses/cs268-11-spring/handouts/AlphaShapes/as_fisher.pdf . Marching cubes uses an N, M, P volume and Alpha Shapes uses Delaunay triangulation as input.